# Mongo writes per day to a collection or database?

Tags: mongodb, statistics

I would like to collect database statistics with mongodb.

I'm interested in learning how many writes per day are performed to my mongo table or database. Is there a simple way to learn how many write operations are performed?

How would you accomplish this goal?

Comment: If running a replica set you could potentially query the oplog collection, which records all operations against a database to find the #. The oplog is a capped collection so you would have to ensure it is large enough to store a days worth of activity. For more on the oplog see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/

Comment: what if they are almost completely in sync? This probably wouldn't be that useful of a measure :/ right?

Comment: The oplog is a capped collection which means it is a fixed size. It will retain all documents written to it until full at which time it will overwrite the oldest documents to write new ones. So if it takes 2 days of your normal write load to fill then you will have 2 days of history at any point in time. If not large enough you can expand the size of this collection.